# Getting "consumer__roles' table doesn't exist: SELECT t.* FROM" in Consumers Drupal 8 module

Tags: drupal

I am using Consumers Drupal 8 module. After installation, I have tried to configure it but getting below error :

```
> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
> table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal88.consumer__roles' doesn't
> exist: SELECT t.* FROM {consumer__roles} t WHERE (entity_id IN
> (:db_condition_placeholder_0, :db_condition_placeholder_1)) AND
> (deleted = :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND (langcode IN
> (:db_condition_placeholder_3, :db_condition_placeholder_4,
> :db_condition_placeholder_5)) ORDER BY delta ASC; Array (
> [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 2
> [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => en
> [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => und [:db_condition_placeholder_5] =>
> zxx ) in
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->loadFromDedicatedTables()
> (line 1261 of
> core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
```

Plugin URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/consumers

Any one help me for this?